# Setting day tabIndex for React Day Picker?

Tags: react-day-picker

By default react-day-picker sets the first day in the calendar to tabindex="0" and the rest of the days to tabindex="-1".

Is it possible to modify this so the first enabled day ends up being tabindex="0" ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this. I wonder if there is a solution in `renderDay` but something more out of the box would be nice.